# Pandas EWM, conditional alpha

Tags: python, pandas

i'd like to use different alpha in EWM function due to data contitions:

```
data.ewm(alpha= X,adjust=False).mean()
```

where X = 1 when yesterday EWM is above 10 and X = 0.5 when yesterday EWM is below 10

is it possible without a loop?

thanks all

Comment: Alpha must be greater than 0

Comment: ok it was just an example. x=1 and x=0.5... i just would like the code to do that

Comment: You did not provide any sample data. You did not show any of your attempts to solve the problem. How do you expect someone to help?

Comment: sorry, i thought it was a real easy one and i was asking because i didn't know how to use a variable alpha.

Comment: @Chris - The question could be written better and could certainly be edited. There is also a syntax issue with the code that could be edited as well. But I don't see the point in including sample data for this question. The OP just wants to know if multiple values of alpha can be used without a loop and it is clear from the pandas API docs that that isn't possible.

Answer (score 1):

No. It isn't possible without a loop unfortunately. You can further refer to the documentation of [ewm](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ewm.html), where, the value of `alpha` is a `float` and not a `list` or another structure where doing this without a loop is possible.