# Converting pandas groupby / apply / ewm calculation with time window to polars

Tags: python, dataframe, group-by, python-polars, moving-average

Due to performance consideration I would like to convert some panda based scripts to polars. I need to perform a groupby and calculate a half-life based on a datetime value. I unfortunately could not really found a cookbook for polars and relied on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73393235/polars-how-to-compute-rolling-ewm-grouped-by-column) to get started and reached the following approximation:

```
import pandas as pd
import polars as pl
import random
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


# Define the list of persons
persons = ['Person A', 'Person B', 'Person C', 'Person D']

# Generate random data for the DataFrame
# start_date = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=365)
df = pd.DataFrame(
        {'person': [random.choice(persons) for _ in range(50)],
         'rating': [random.randint(75, 110) for _ in range(50)],
         'date'  : [datetime(2022, 6, 1, 0, 0, 0)
                    + timedelta(days=random.randint(0, 365))
                    for _ in range(50)]}
        )

df.sort_values(['date'], inplace=True)
# To be used with polars
dl = pl.from_dataframe(df)

# Function to convert
df['EWM_30d'] = df.groupby(
        by='person', sort=False).apply(
        lambda x: x['rating'].ewm(halflife=('30d'), times=x['date']
                                  ).mean().shift(1, fill_value=80).round(2)
).to_numpy()

# Initial polars version
dl = dl.rolling(
        'date', by='person', period="100000d").agg(
        pl.col('rating').ewm_mean(half_life=30).shift(1, fill_value=80).last().alias('EWM_30d'))
```

I have managed to do something remotely similar however it has several flaws:

- As I could not find something similar either explicitly or implicitly to pd.expanding() I am using rolling(), with a very long time window which looks a bit awkward
- I am using a half_life of 30 rows instead of a '30d' temporal window based on the datetime 'date' column.
  While the speed is there, it is not the exact same operation and the results are different from the ones I get with pandas.

Comment: I looked in the Pandas codebase to see how it calculates this. Essentially, it computes `deltas = np.diff(times) / halflife`, then goes to this function, https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/1387c4fa09ca7bb13a7f1e13ecd171aebe8fef46/pandas/_libs/window/aggregations.pyx#L1738. I don't think Polars has an equivalent? See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60493542/pandas-ewm-conditional-alpha

Comment: polars has `upsample` which might be like `expanding`. I'm not a pandas expert so I don't know how to bridge the gap.

Comment: @DeanMacGregor `expanding` is a little different: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/4799 - It's basically rolling with `period=f"{df.height}i"}` or you can use `.cumulative_eval` but `period` can't take expressions and cumulative_eval duplicates work.